# Class path resource inside JHipster application

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

Inside my JHipster (version 6.4.1) application in resources I have directory called *static*, where I put JSON file which is required for one of services. File is called *standards.json*. 
In my service I want to read this file in quite simple way:

```
try {
        ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource("static/standards.json");
        byte[] bdata = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(cpr.getInputStream());
        String content = new String(bdata, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Gson g = new Gson();
        data = g.fromJson(content, StandardLevel[].class);

        // here I am doing something with data
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

But unfortunately I am getting runtime error:

```
class path resource [static/standards.json] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

It is strange, because when I was doing it in this same way in "clean" Spring Boot application, without JHipster, everything was working correctly. 
Any ideas why it is not working here? Or how should I use static JSOn files, which are required for my backend side?

Comment: Is it "static/standards.json" or "static/data/standards.json"? Just to confirm it's not a simple typo :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's 'static/standards.json'.

Comment: Project relative location is `src/main/resources/static/standards.json` , right? Do you run the app using mvnw?